# How to get receiver name or user_id on sharing a message through Facebook Messenger

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I referred this link for sending a message through facebook messenger.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog

Is there any possibilities to get the user name to whom we send? Suppose I login & while sending the message to some XXX is it possible to get the name XXX? I found many tutorials but I didn't find any solutions.

I want to send a message and not notifications.

So I finally understood that there is no such possibilities. Now coming on to request when sending from facebook is it possible to save the user name to whom we send?

Comment: `FBMessage Dialog` doesn't provide any information to user, it will open facebook application and control will be transfered to it. Your app can't control over it. :)

Comment: Is there any other solutions for it? My app is like user has to refer a facebook friend and if the user accepts he/she will get a bonus. In this situation I need to get the sender's name.

Comment: that´s not allowed anyway. don´t incentivize sending a message for a bonus. you can only do this with an app request > giving the inviter a bonus when the receiver accepts the invitation.

Comment: so while sending the request can we able to save the sender's name or ID??

Comment: You will be able to get that info when the receiving user accepts the request.

Comment: @CBroe can you guide me? Is there any samples available?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1 / Be aware that your app needs to have a canvas presence and be in “Games” category, otherwise you can not use requests.